# Creating an expanding gesture for Leap Motion in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gesture, leap-motion

I am quite new to unity and programming. I am trying to create an expanding gesture with leap motion.
Starting position = both palms together like a clap
End position = when palms are separated
When this occurs I want to move objects to new positions

The code below was creating a gesture where you move both hands up slowly, i wanted to know how i can modify it to have it doing the expand gesture.

void LeapMotion::liftGesture(int numberHands, std::vector palmNormals, std::vector palmVelocities) {

```
if ((numberHands == 2) &&
    (palmNormals[0].x < 0.4f) && (palmNormals[1].x < 0.4f) &&
    (palmNormals[0].y > 0.9f) && (palmNormals[1].y > 0.9f) &&
    (palmNormals[0].z < 0.4f) && (palmNormals[1].z < 0.4f) &&
    (palmVelocities[0].z > 50.0f) && (palmVelocities[1].z > 50.0f) &&
    (palmVelocities[0].z < 300.0f) && (palmVelocities[1].z < 300.0f)) {

    //MOVE OBJECTS TO NEW POSITIONS 
}
```

}

If someone can please help it would mean alot. Im struggling.